# Cumulative sum based on consecutive values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a very large database containing over 40 million records for GPS tracks for mail delivery. I want to be able to figure out how long a letter carrier has been stopped for. So, when the carrier's distance is registered at 0, and every consecutive 0 following, I would like to know the cumulative time spent stopped. I would also like the summing to stop when anything higher than 0 is registered and to start again when a 0 is registered.  This is what I have got so far:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Distance = 0 THEN SUM(Time_s) OVER (ORDER BY [ID] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)  
    WHEN Distance <0 THEN NULL
END as StopTime

FROM data
ORDER BY ID
```

This is the result:

```
ID  Distance    Time_s  StopTime
1   6            899    NULL
2   0            789    1688
3   16           740    NULL
4   0            70     2498
5   0            50     2548
6   0            585    3133
7   0            10     3143
8   5            329    NULL
9   6            394    NULL
10  0            570    4436
```

I am clearly not telling the query to start the counting over again every time the consecutive zero's are interrupted by anything greater than zero. This is the result I want:

```
ID  Distance    Time_s  StopTime
1   6            899    NULL
2   0            789    789
3   16           740    NULL
4   0            70     70
5   0            50     130
6   0            585    715
7   0            10     725
8   5            329    NULL
9   6            394    NULL
10  0            570    570
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a group as the cumulative count of the non-zero values before any given value.  Then you can use that group for the cumulative sum.

```
select d.id, d.distance, d.time_s,
       (case when d.distance = 0
             then sum(case when d.distance = 0 then d.time_s end) over (partition by grp order by id)
        end) as StopTime
from (select d.*,
             sum(case when distance = 0 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from data d
     ) d;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried running this on my dataset and all of the values in StopTime were returned as Null. In the partition by statement I changed 'by group' to 'by grp'.

Comment: @hurlski . . . I had the wrong `case` condition.  It should have been on `distance`.

Comment: . This works but it is including the time_s from the previous moving record in the calculation: [here's my result](http://screencast.com/t/Ja6Zj8ZDBCG)                                       Is there a way to tell it to skip a row and then start the summing to only include times with 0 distance?

Comment: @hurlski . . . Good point.  A conditional sum fixes that problem.